# Kentico 9.2 modify administration pages in WebApp

Tags: deployment, kentico

i just modify an file from kentico CMSApp project. 
The path: 
CMS\CMSModules\Content\CMSDesk\Properties\Menu.aspx

i change an input from cms:CMSTextBox to cms:MediaSelector.

In kentico dashboard -> pages -> Properties -> Navigation

After that i deploy the CMSApp_MVC project, and copied the files from the folder i mentioned.

Now it doesnt work on production environment.
Help please.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended **not to** modify Kentico system files unless you have no other options. Your current change is not supported and instead of doing that I would recommend to create a **[Custom page type field](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Creating+page+types)** using whatever **Form control** you like to hold your value - just don't change the file you mentioned directly.

You can then work with that field just like you would with any other Document/TreeNode field.

PS: Kentico 9.2 does not exist.

Comment: Yes, 9.2 doesn't exists, my mistake.
It sounds the solution i am looking cant be applied, since i am using MVC , and in Controller Context , i just return the TreeNode Currentnode.
And in the View i just manipulate the entire node Data collection, and build my Menu. Ofcourse i could use .WithAllData, that loads the custom properties that i created, but i loose my order, that is independent of page types, since the fact that my menu have some page types. 

But thanks Enn, you gave me another idea.